# Creating adjacency list with O(1) insert operation

Tags: c, optimization, data-structures, time-complexity, graph-theory

What I have currently is this:

```
void addEdge(listNode **adjacencyList, int firstVertex, int secondVertex, int cost) {
    if (firstVertex == secondVertex) return;

    attachNeighbor(firstVertex, cost, adjacencyList[secondVertex]);
    attachNeighbor(secondVertex, cost, adjacencyList[firstVertex]);
}

void attachNeighbor(int id, int cost, listNode *root) {
    if (root->vertex == 0) {
        root->vertex = id;
        root->cost = cost;
    } else {
        listNode *neighbor;
        neighbor = (listNode *) malloc(sizeof(listNode));
        neighbor->cost = cost;
        neighbor->vertex = id;

        listNode *next = root;
        while (next->next != NULL) {
            next = next->next;
        }

        next->next = neighbor;
    }
}
```

however, with 10k+ vertices and over a million of edges it's really slow, because each insert operation takes O(Number of neighbors). Later what I have to with this is simply just iterate through all neighbors once, so I don't need a fast retrieval. I thought about doubly linked list and keeping the pointer to last node, then when I have to iterate I would just go backwards, but I am not sure how to do that in C

Comment: if it was c++ i would have gone with `vector< vector<> >` but as you are using c linked list would suffice, I did not get it why you want double linked list though.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put the new node in the front of the list, changing the root each time:

```
void addEdge(listNode **adjacencyList, int firstVertex, int secondVertex, int cost) {
    if (firstVertex == secondVertex) return;

    attachNeighbor(firstVertex, cost, adjacencyList + secondVertex);
    attachNeighbor(secondVertex, cost, adjacencyList + firstVertex);
}

void attachNeighbor(int id, int cost, listNode **pRoot) {
    listNode *root = *pRoot;
    if (root->vertex == 0) {
        root->vertex = id;
        root->cost = cost;
    } else {
        listNode *neighbor;
        neighbor = (listNode *) malloc(sizeof(listNode));
        neighbor->cost = cost;
        neighbor->vertex = id;
        neighbor->next = root;
        *pRoot = neighbor;
    }
}
```

Comment: God damn, I have to refresh my algorithm skills :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about doubly linked list and keeping the pointer to last node

You don't need a doubly linked list, all you need is keeping a pointer to the last node.

Make a second array, say, `adjacencyListEnd`, and pass a pointer to its element to `attachNeighbor`:

```
void attachNeighbor(int id, int cost, listNode *root, listNode **last) {
    if (root->vertex == 0) {
        root->vertex = id;
        root->cost = cost;
        *last = root;
    } else {
        listNode *neighbor;
        neighbor = (listNode *) malloc(sizeof(listNode));
        neighbor->cost = cost;
        neighbor->vertex = id;
        (*last)->next = neighbor;
        *last = neighbor;  
    }
}
```

You call it like this:

```
void addEdge(listNode **adjacencyList, int firstVertex, int secondVertex, int cost) {
    if (firstVertex == secondVertex) return;

    attachNeighbor(firstVertex, cost, adjacencyList[secondVertex], &adjacencyListEnd[secondVertex]);
    attachNeighbor(secondVertex, cost, adjacencyList[firstVertex], &adjacencyList[firstVertex]);
}
```